# Stream Desktop via VLC

Tags: stream, udp, vlc

I am trying to stream my desktop using VLC and watch the stream on anoter network. so this means that I can set up the stream on my home laptop and when i go to work, i can still view the stream from the work network.

I have so far done these steps:

1. Clicked on Stream in the media tab
2. Selected capture device
3. switched to Desktop and gave it 25 fps
4. clicked stream
5. selected the screen source
6. selected udp and pressed add
7. gave it an address and port
8. selected transcode
9. Selected Stream all...
10. Pressed Stream
11. Went on my 4G network on my phone and used the udp link on the vlc but it doesn't show the screen

It shows the screen on the same network

Know any reason why.

Answer (score 0):

You must to do a port forward on your home router, so you can access the streaming laptop from anywhere